# commands not found when running script

Tags: bash, shell, grep, command, pid

I have a very basic script that keeps spitting back that the commands are not found. Ive looked all over this site and can not find an answer that works for me. The path to bash is correct. Ive checked the script with od. Ive run dos2unix. None of this helps me.

SCRIPT:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    HYBRISPROC=`ps -eo pid,command | grep [h]ybris | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo "Looking for Hybris..."
    echo $HYBRISPROC
```

RESULTS:

```
    ./HybrisStopStart.sh: line 5: ps: command not found
    ./HybrisStopStart.sh: line 5: grep: command not found
    ./HybrisStopStart.sh: line 5: awk: command not found
    ./HybrisStopStart.sh: line 5: grep: command not found
    Looking for Hybris...
```

Any ideas? If I run the command just on its own it works fine. Ive tried it as sudo as well and et the same results.

TIA

Comment: Just as a side note, if you do `grep [h]ybris` then you do not have to `grep -v grep`.

Comment: Try looking at "pgrep" command... "pgrep hybris"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about it?

```
#!/bin/bash
HYBRISPROC=`ps -eo pid,command | grep [h]ybris | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "Looking for Hybris..."
echo "$HYBRISPROC"
```

(OR)

```
#!/bin/bash
HYBRISPROC="ps -eo pid,command | grep [h]ybris | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'"
echo "Looking for Hybris..."
bash -c "$HYBRISPROC"
```

(OR)

```
#!/bin/bash
HYBRISPROC="ps -eo pid,command | grep [h]ybris | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'"
echo "Looking for Hybris..."
eval "$HYBRISPROC"
```

**TOTALY:**

you can see the difference:

```
#!/bin/bash
LS=`ls -l`
echo $LS    #nasty way
echo 
echo "$LS"  #good way
```

Comment: This returned the full entry of PS...as if I had just done ps -ef | grep hybris. More than what I need but heading in the right direction. Im just looking to cull out the PIDs.

Comment: I copied your command..I introduced you ways to run from variables...that works I think

Comment: If I remove the bash -c and replace with just echo I get exactly what im looking for. I guess the difference is the "" around $HYBRISPROC on the last line. Thanks

Comment: Thought id come back and post what i eventually ended up using...since Hybris was returning two pids I decided to go with looking for and stopping tomcat instead...

`HYBRISPROC=$(ps -ef | grep [t]omcat | awk '/[t]omcat/{print $2}')`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

> PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin"

before code. Looks like bin directory is not on your path. So the commands are not found.